# python3 subprocess delivers no output

Tags: python, groovy, subprocess

I have the following problem. In a groovy prog I start a python program that starts a subprocess. The output of this subprocess will be read into a variable. (os is ubuntu)

```
git = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, env=environ)
data = git.stdout.read();
```

But the variable is always empty and I have no idea why.
(Starting the Python within a shell it works)

Comment: What are the `args` you're passing? Do you depend on any environment variables, because those can be very different depending on where you're launching from.

Comment: Try trapping and reading `stderr`?

Comment: The output s going out stderr, if you want the output use `check_output` instead of Popen and it will be a lot more informative

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the output is going out stderr which you are not capturing, you would need to add a `stderr = subprocess.PIPE` and use `communicate` but if you are using python >= 2.7 then `check_output` would be the best to use, any non-zero exit status would raise a `CalledProcessError`:

```
from subprocess import check_output,CalledProcessError
try:
   data = check_output(args, env=environ)
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)
else:
    print(data)
```

Comment: Note: do not use `stderr=PIPE` with `check_output()`. To merge stderr into stdout, use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
git = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=environ)
data, err = git.communicate()
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
print(err.decode('utf-8'))
```